# Unable to Install pyslalib package using python2.7 / MINGW on Windows 10

Tags: python, mingw, windows-10

I'm trying to install the [pyslalib package](https://github.com/scottransom/pyslalib) using python 2.7 on Windows 10 and keep getting the following:

"collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

message when I try to run "python setup.py install".  I think this might be an issue with my mingw configuration, but I can't seem to locate the problem.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated. I've eaten up most of the weekend struggling with this.

Thanks,

The output errors are:

```
C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a(dmmes01026.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_C__build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a'
C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a(dmmes00281.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_C__build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a'
C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a(dmmes00105.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_C__build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a'
C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a(dmmes00253.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_C__build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a'
C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a(dmmes00227.o):(.idata$7+0x0): undefined reference to `_head_C__build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a'
C:\Python27\libs/libpython27.a(dmmes00712.o):(.idata$7+0x0): more undefined references to `_head_C__build27_cpython_PCBuild_libpython27_a' follow
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a problem I had recently. I think there is a problem with the `libpython27.a` that comes included with Python (I'm on version 2.7.10). Creating my own `libpython27.a` from the `python27.dll` as per the instructions found [here](http://sebsauvage.net/python/mingw.html) fixed the problem.

> To create Python extensions, you need to link against the Python
>   library. Unfortunately, most Python distributions are provided with
>   `Python22.lib`, a library in Microsoft Visual C++ format. GCC expects a
>   .a file (`libpython22.a` to be precise.). Here's how to convert
>   `python22.lib` to `libpython22.a`:
>
> 1. Download pexport (from here or
>      https://web.archive.org/web/20000829082204/http://starship.python.net/crew/kernr/mingw32/pexports-0.42h.zip).
> 2. Get
>      `Python22.dll` (it should be somewhere on your harddrive).
> 3. Run :
>      `pexports python22.dll > python22.def` This will extract all symbols
>      from `python22.dll` and write them into `python22.def`.
> 4. Run : `dlltool --dllname python22.dll --def python22.def --output-lib libpython22.a` This will create `libpython22.a` (`dlltool` is part of MinGW utilities).
> 5. Copy `libpython22.a` to `c:\python22\libs\` (in the same directory as
>      `python22.lib`).
>
> This trick should work for all Python versions,
>   including future releases of Python. You can also use this trick to
>   convert other libraries.

Comment: I had the same problem, your tip helped me solve my problem.

Comment: the link was offline, archive.org had a copy : https://web.archive.org/web/20000829082204/http://starship.python.net/crew/kernr/mingw32/pexports-0.42h.zip edited

Comment: The problem seems to have been resolved in Python 2.7.11 (released December 5th), so now the easiest solution is just to update.