# Unable to install leven package using Python27 MingGW on Windows 10 collect2.exe error

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, mingw, windows-10

I'm trying to install the leven package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/leven/) using python 2.7.10, windows 10, and mingw. I'm getting the following error:

"collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Any help on this would be greatly appreciate it. I've been trying to install this for days now. I've overcome several problems includying a previous collect2.exe error using this solution: [Unable to Install pyslalib package using python2.7 / MINGW on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32555087/unable-to-install-pyslalib-package-using-python2-7-mingw-on-windows-10)

However, after fixing that issue another error surged. Here is the error:

```
 C:\bin\leven-1.0.4.tar\dist\leven-1.0.4>python setup.py install
 running install
 running bdist_egg
 running egg_info
 writing requirements to leven.egg-info\requires.txt
 writing leven.egg-info\PKG-INFO
 writing top-level names to leven.egg-info\top_level.txt
 writing dependency_links to leven.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
 reading manifest file 'leven.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
 reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
 writing manifest file 'leven.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
 installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
 running install_lib
 running build_py
 running build_ext
 building 'leven._levenshtein' extension
 C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -Ileven -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c leven/_levenshtein.cpp -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o
 leven/_levenshtein.cpp: In function 'void __Pyx_RaiseArgtupleInvalid(const char*, int, Py_ssize_t, Py_ssize_t, Py_ssize_t)':
 leven/_levenshtein.cpp:1400:59: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat]
 leven/_levenshtein.cpp:1400:59: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char*', but argument 5 has type 'Py_ssize_t {aka int}' [-Wformat]
 leven/_levenshtein.cpp:1400:59: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat]
 leven/_levenshtein.cpp:1400:59: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
 writing build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.def
 C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\g++.exe -mdll -static --entry _DllMain@12 -out-implib=build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\lib_levenshtein.a --def build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.def -s build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27\PCbuild -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win32-2.7\leven\_levenshtein.pyd
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xc9): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x114): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x280): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_MemoryError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x293): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x2b9): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x2cc): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x2f2): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ValueError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x305): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x32b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ValueError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x33e): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x364): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_IOError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x377): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x39d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_IndexError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x3b0): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x3d6): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_OverflowError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x3e9): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x40f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ArithmeticError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x422): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x448): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ArithmeticError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x45b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x47e): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x491): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x4b1): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x4c4): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x502): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_FromString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x515): undefined reference to `_imp__PyImport_Import'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x53e): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_FromString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x555): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttr'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x5a5): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x5b0): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x5f1): undefined reference to `_imp__PyOS_snprintf'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x60a): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_WarnEx'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x62f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ValueError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x63a): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x6f9): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_FromString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x728): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_FromFormat'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x739): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_FromString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x79f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCode_New'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x80b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Malloc'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x89e): undefined reference to `_imp__PyMem_Realloc'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x903): undefined reference to `_imp__PyModule_GetDict'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x91c): undefined reference to `_imp___PyThreadState_Current'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x927): undefined reference to `_imp__PyFrame_New'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x93d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTraceBack_Here'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x998): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_FromString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xaa7): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_Size'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xaec): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_GetItem'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xb23): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_GetItem'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xb9b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_GetItem'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xc51): undefined reference to `_imp___PyString_Eq'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xcdc): undefined reference to `_imp___PyString_Eq'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xd40): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicodeUCS2_Compare'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xd50): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xde2): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicodeUCS2_Compare'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xdf2): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xe53): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_Next'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xe7b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_AsString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xe94): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xe9f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xeb9): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xecf): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xeef): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_AsString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xf08): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xf13): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xf8a): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_Size'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xfa0): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_Size'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0xfea): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_AsStringAndSize'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x1012): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x1048): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_AsStringAndSize'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x1070): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x14d1): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttr'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x14f8): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_New'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x1509): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicode_Type'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x1549): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_Call'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x15b6): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_New'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x15e3): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_Call'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x161c): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x163e): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x165c): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTraceBack_Type'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x166e): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x1684): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x16ca): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_NormalizeException'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x16e6): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x16fc): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x1716): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_BaseException'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x1737): undefined reference to `_imp__PyType_IsSubtype'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x1748): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x1753): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x176b): undefined reference to `_imp___PyThreadState_Current'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x1911): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_TrueStruct'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x191a): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_ZeroStruct'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x1927): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x1946): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_IsTrue'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x19a2): undefined reference to `_imp__PyGILState_Ensure'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x19b3): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ZeroDivisionError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x19be): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x19cb): undefined reference to `_imp__PyGILState_Release'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x1a1d): undefined reference to `_imp__PyFloat_FromDouble'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x1a46): undefined reference to `_imp__PyLong_FromUnsignedLong'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x1f1c): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_Type'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x1fbd): undefined reference to `_imp__PyOS_snprintf'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x1fc5): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_GetVersion'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x202b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyOS_snprintf'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x2044): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_WarnEx'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x2059): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_New'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x207b): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_FromStringAndSize'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x20b5): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_InitModule4'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x20cd): undefined reference to `_imp__PyModule_GetDict'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x20e9): undefined reference to `_imp__PyImport_AddModule'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x2110): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_SetAttrString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x2131): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_FromStringAndSize'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x2137): undefined reference to `_imp__PyString_InternFromString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x2159): undefined reference to `_imp__PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeUTF8'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x21b9): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_SetAttrString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x2203): undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttr'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x221f): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_NameError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x222a): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x22f2): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCode_New'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x2377): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_ZeroStruct'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x239c): undefined reference to `_imp__PyCFunction_NewEx'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x23c1): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_SetItem'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x23e1): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_New'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x2406): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_SetItem'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x2429): undefined reference to `_imp__PyDict_SetItem'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x24a7): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Occurred'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x24bc): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ImportError'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x24c7): undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
 build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\leven\_levenshtein.o:_levenshtein.cpp:(.text+0x2558): undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_Pack'
 collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CodeBlocks\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe' failed with exit status 1

 C:\bin\leven-1.0.4.tar\dist\leven-1.0.4>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

These errors are references to python core library (`libpython27.a` from `C:\Python27\libs`). Make sure:

1. it is exists and match your gcc architecture. These errors are often appear when you are using 32-bit gcc and 64-bit libraries.
2. I see you are using `pexports` to create this library, it may work wrong too, see http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msvc_and_mingw_dlls - it can add additional _ to all exported names and you need to strip it as described:

> pexports python27.dll | sed "s/^_//" > python27.def

3. Python standard Windows distribution built with MSVC 2008 and linked to `msvcr90.dll`, when mingw-gcc linking binaries with `msvcrt.dll` - it can cause a lot of problems(crashes). You need to follow [this guide](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Use_the_GCC_specs_file) to make your gcc link with `msvcr90.dll`

Comment: Thanks @vitalyster. You are right, I'm runnign on windows 10 64 bit, but I have python 32 bit installed. I did that, bc one of the python packages I needed was only supported on 32bit python.

Comment: Also, I'm trying to run the pexports command you posted, but I get 'sed' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: I searched in my computer, and I have 3 sed.exe. One in git\bin, another in octave\bin\ and another in appdata\....\github\... They have different sizes. Should I use one of those?

Comment: Hey I tried steps 1 and 2 multiple times and didn't work.. and I'm not sure I understand the guide in point 3. I understand what I'm supposed to do (making gcc link msvcr90.dll instead of msvr90.dll), but not sure how to follow. Any suggestions? I think that guide is above my knowledge.

Comment: Especially because the guide is from 2008, and some things in **specs** file have changed, so not sure if the modifications would actually hurt my system

Comment: Actually, I did the modifications to the specs file, using the 3rd method, and didn't work :/

Comment: Modifying gcc specs is needed only when these linking errors are already gone and you already able to link target library, so 2. is much more important, try to check .def file, it should have the same names as they appeared in linker error messages

Comment: Actually, I just successfully compile leven library, I saw these errors when using wrong dlltool (x86-64), and they gone when I got 32 bit version. I call pexports without sed, and it works

Comment: Oops, I got tired of having 32-64 issues, so I reinstalled python and all the other tools I use to 64 bit. Gonna try again to compile leven now.

Comment: I'm getting this error when trying to run 'python setup.py install: http://pastebin.com/7FDb9gRr

Comment: We are using --compiler=mingw32, why msvc?

Comment: Bc I kept having compilation errors. I couldn't build any package written on c++. When I switched to msvc I was able to build other python packages. So now I know that the compiler is working, but I cannot compile only the leven package.

Comment: So msvc issues is completely different topic, try to ask new question