# PyQt5 Windows built failure

Tags: python, windows, build, pyqt5

I'm trying to build PyQt5 in Windows 7 using mingw53_32 toolchain taken from 5.9.1. Configure step passed successfully, but got many linking errors while building, here is the end of `make` output:

```
C:\Work\PyQt5_gpl-5.9>mingw32-make.exe
<...>
./release\qpycore_qjsonvalue.o:qpycore_qjsonvalue.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `_imp__PyBool_Type'
./release\qpycore_qjsonvalue.o:qpycore_qjsonvalue.cpp:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `_imp__PyFloat_Type'
./release\qpycore_qjsonvalue.o:qpycore_qjsonvalue.cpp:(.text+0x185): undefined reference to `_imp__PyBool_Type'
./release\qpycore_qjsonvalue.o:qpycore_qjsonvalue.cpp:(.text+0x1a8): undefined reference to `_imp__PyFloat_Type'
./release\qpycore_qjsonvalue.o:qpycore_qjsonvalue.cpp:(.text+0x434): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_TrueStruct'
./release\qpycore_qobject_getattr.o:qpycore_qobject_getattr.cpp:(.text+0x141): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_AttributeError'
./release\qpycore_qobject_helpers.o:qpycore_qobject_helpers.cpp:(.text+0x5e1): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_AttributeError'
./release\qpycore_types.o:qpycore_types.cpp:(.text+0xe7c): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.Release:893: recipe for target 'release\QtCore.dll' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [release\QtCore.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Work/PyQt5_gpl-5.9/QtCore'
Makefile:36: recipe for target 'release' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [release] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Work/PyQt5_gpl-5.9/QtCore'
Makefile:76: recipe for target 'sub-QtCore-make_first-ordered' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [sub-QtCore-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

Could anybody suggest me how to fix these errors?

Comment: Which arguments did you pass to `configure.py`? I'm not sure what's causing your particular error, but I have been successfully building `PyQt5` with `MinGW` from an [`MSYS`](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys) terminal and configuring with `python configure.py --confirm-license --spec win32-g++ QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=”-D_hypot=hypot “`

Comment: Actually, those link errors look related to the python libs. Do you have a `libpythonXX.a` in the `lib` folder of your Python installation? Which Python version are you running? I had problems with the `.a` that shipped with Python 2.7.10 and had to [create my own from the .dll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32589305/3419537). However, before messing around with that I would first try and build from MSYS and see if that solves the problem.