# undefined reference to `__imp_PyFloat_Type' using f2py on Windows 10

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, mingw-w64, f2py

I am trying to compile a Fortran 90 file with f2py, to use in a Python module. The file is composed of two subroutines. I can compile the file, using `gfortran ljlib3.f90` in the command window, but I get errors when trying to compile the subroutine with f2py.

I am using Python(x,y) on Win 10 (Python 2.7.10) and Mingw-w64 (all properly installed). It's difficult because this is someone else's code from the tutorial, where in my case all works fine until almost the end of the compiling (when comparing with the tutorial).

Here are the subroutines in the file ljlib3.f90:

```
subroutine EnergyForces(Pos, L, rc, PEnergy, Forces, Dim, NAtom)
implicit none
integer, intent(in) :: Dim, NAtom
real(8), intent(in), dimension(0:NAtom-1, 0:Dim-1) :: Pos
real(8), intent(in) :: L, rc
real(8), intent(out) :: PEnergy
real(8), intent(inout), dimension(0:NAtom-1, 0:Dim-1) :: Forces
!f2py intent(in,out) :: Forces
real(8), dimension(Dim) :: rij, Fij, Posi
real(8) :: d2, id2, id6, id12
real(8) :: rc2, Shift
integer :: i, j
PEnergy = 0.
Forces = 0.
Shift = -4. * (rc**(-12) - rc**(-6))
rc2 = rc * rc
do i = 0, NAtom - 1
    !store Pos(i,:) in a temporary array for faster access in j loop
    Posi = Pos(i,:)
    do j = i + 1, NAtom - 1
        rij = Pos(j,:) - Posi
        rij = rij - L * dnint(rij / L)
        !compute only the squared distance and compare to squared cut
        d2 = sum(rij * rij)
        if (d2 > rc2) then
            cycle
        end if
        id2 = 1. / d2            !inverse squared distance
        id6 = id2 * id2 * id2    !inverse sixth distance
        id12 = id6 * id6         !inverse twelvth distance
        PEnergy = PEnergy + 4. * (id12 - id6) + Shift
        Fij = rij * ((-48. * id12 + 24. * id6) * id2)
        Forces(i,:) = Forces(i,:) + Fij
        Forces(j,:) = Forces(j,:) - Fij
    enddo
enddo
end subroutine

subroutine VVIntegrate(Pos, Vel, Accel, L, CutSq, dt, KEnergy, PEnergy, Dim, 
NAtom)
implicit none
integer, intent(in) :: Dim, NAtom
real(8), intent(in) :: L, CutSq, dt
real(8), intent(inout), dimension(0:NAtom-1, 0:Dim-1) :: Pos, Vel, Accel
!f2py intent(in,out) :: Pos, Vel, Accel
real(8), intent(out) :: KEnergy, PEnergy
external :: EnergyForces
Pos = Pos + dt * Vel + 0.5 * dt*dt * Accel
Vel = Vel + 0.5 * dt * Accel
call EnergyForces(Pos, L, CutSq, PEnergy, Accel, Dim, NAtom)
Vel = Vel + 0.5 * dt * Accel
KEnergy = 0.5 * sum(Vel*Vel)
end subroutine
```

Notice the `!f2py intent(in,out)...` directives are also used in subroutines.

After using the f2py command:

```
f2py -c -m ljlib ljlib3.f90 --fcompiler=gnu95 compiler=mingw32
```

The following error appears:

```
C:\Program_Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.2.0-posix-sjlj-rt_v5-
rev1\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -Wall -g -shared 
c:\users\pc2012\appdata\local\temp\tmp_pzjlc\Release\users 
\pc2012\appdata\local\temp\tmp_pzjlc\src.win32-2.7\ljlibmodule.o 
c:\users\pc2012\appdata\local\temp\tmp_pzjlc\Release\users 
\pc2012\appdata\local\temp\tmp_pzjlc\src.win32-2.7\fortranobject.o 
c:\users\pc2012\appdata\local\temp\tmp_pzjlc\Release\ljlib3.o -
LC:\Program_Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.2.0-posix-sjlj-rt_v5-
rev1\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\7.2.0 -LC:\Python27\libs -
LC:\Python27\PCbuild -lpython27 -lgfortran -o .\ljlib.pyd
c:\users\pc2012\appdata\local\temp\tmp_pzjlc\Release\users 
\pc2012\appdata\local\temp\tmp_pzjlc\src.win32-
2.7\ljlibmodule.o:ljlibmodule.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to 
`__imp_PyFloat_Type'
c:\users\pc2012\appdata\local\temp\tmp_pzjlc\Release\users 
\pc2012\appdata\local\temp\tmp_pzjlc\src.win32-
2.7\ljlibmodule.o:ljlibmodule.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to 
`__imp_PyType_IsSubtype'
c:\users\pc2012\appdata\local\temp\tmp_pzjlc\Release\users 
\pc2012\appdata\local\temp\tmp_pzjlc\src.win32-
2.7\ljlibmodule.o:ljlibmodule.c:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to 
`__imp_PyNumber_Float'  ...

error: Command "C:\Program_Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.2.0-posix-sjlj-rt_v5-
rev1\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe -Wall -g -Wall -g -shared 
c:\users\pc2012\appdata\local\temp\tmp_pzjlc\Release\users 
\pc2012\appdata\local\temp\tmp_pzjlc\src.win32-2.7\ljlibmodule.o 
c:\users\pc2012\appdata\local\temp\tmp_pzjlc\Release\users 
\pc2012\appdata\local\temp\tmp_pzjlc\src.win32-2.7\fortranobject.o 
c:\users\pc2012\appdata\local\temp\tmp_pzjlc\Release\ljlib3.o -
LC:\Program_Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.2.0-posix-sjlj-rt_v5-
rev1\mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\7.2.0 -LC:\Python27\libs -
LC:\Python27\PCbuild -lpython27 -lgfortran -o .\ljlib.pyd" failed with exit 
status 1
```

An error occurs after many `undefined reference to`....'`. I guess that this is some PATH issue but I am not sure.

Comment: Welcome. Be sure to take the [tour]. Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions,

Comment: Does anybody have any solution to this problem? According to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32555087/unable-to-install-pyslalib-package-using-python2-7-mingw-on-windows-10/32589305#32589305) the problem occurs in Python 2.7.10 which I installed with the last version of Python (x,y). Some others claimed that this is resolved in Python 2.7.11, which unfortunately is not included in Python (x,y).

Comment: The answer you link to contains 5 points to follow. Did you do that? What happened? I am not too convinced the comment about the exact version id completely correct.

Comment: I solved the problem by removing Python(x,y) that comes with Python 2.7.10 and install Anaconda (with Python 2.7.14). During execution, I noticed that it founds Python27.dll and creates corresponding .def and .a files and gives the correct response without errors.

Comment: Is there any reason now to not vote to close this question as a duplicate of the question you linked?

Comment: This question can be considered as an updated version of the one I previously linked. It can be useful to future users of the current version of Python(x,y) that comes with errors when using f2py.

Comment: I was not talking about deleting, but about marking it as a duplicate. It does not have any answer, after all.

Answer (score 0):

```html
import numpy as np

def EnergyForces(Pos, L, rc, Natom):
 PEnergy = 0.
 Forces = np.zeros([Natom,3])
 Posi = np.zeros([1,3])
 Shift = -4.*(rc**(-12) - rc**(-6))
 rc2 = rc*rc
 for i in range(Natom):
         Posi = Pos[i,:]
         for j in range(i+1,Natom):
              rij = Pos[j,:] - Posi
              rij = rij - L*np.round(rij / L)
              d2 = np.linalg.norm(rij)**2
              if d2 > rc2:
                  continue
              id2 = 1. / d2           
              id6 = id2 * id2 * id2 
              id12 = id6 * id6         
              PEnergy = PEnergy + 4. * (id12 - id6) + Shift
              Fij = rij * ((-48. * id12 + 24. * id6) * id2)
              Forces[i,:] = Forces[i,:] + Fij
              Forces[j,:] = Forces[j,:] - Fij
 
 return PEnergy, Forces


def VVIntegrate(Pos, Vel, Accel, L, rc, dt, Natom):
 Pos = Pos + dt*Vel + 0.5*dt*dt*Accel
 Vel = Vel + 0.5*dt*Accel
 PEnergy, Accel = EnergyForces(Pos, L, rc, Natom) #FOR THE NEW FORCES
 Vel = Vel + 0.5*dt*Accel
 KEnergy = 0.5*np.linalg.norm(Vel)**2

 return Pos, Vel, Accel, KEnergy, PEnergy
```

Comment: Can you please update your answer to include an explanation as to what your code does?